# How can I setup default content type for a Document Library in SharePoint Online using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I am developing a PowerShell Script and this script is supposed to do following task:

1. Create a Document Library (E.g. Financian Documents)
2. Attach a Content Type to this Document Library
3. Setup this Content Type as a Default Content Type

I am stuck at third point and not able to setup default content type using PowerShell. Here is the code that I am using to update Content Type:

**Code**

```
$ctidary = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]
$ctidary.insert($ctID)
$list.rootfolder.uniquecontenttypeorder = $ctidary
$list.rootfolder.update()
$clientContext.executeQuery()
```

**Error**

```
Cannot find an overload for "insert" and the argument count: "1"
```

Please suggest me how can I set up a Content Type as a default Content type for a Document Library in SharePoint Online using Powershell Script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my scenario below solution worked for my SharePoint Online Tenant:

```
$cttitle = "<Title of Content Type>"
$list = $clientContext.web.lists.GetByTitle("<Title of List/Library>")
$clientContext.load($list)
$clientContext.load($list.contenttypes)
$clientContext.executeQuery()

$currentOrder = $list.ContentTypes
$result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]

foreach ($ct in $currentOrder)
{
    if ($ct.Name.Contains($cttitle))
    {
        $result.Add($ct.Id)
    }
}

$list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $result
$list.RootFolder.Update()

$clientContext.executeQuery()
```

In this solution, instead of iterating through all the content types when I tried to add `$ct` directly in `$result`, it didn't worked for me, So I iterated through all the content type and retrieved ID of Content Type.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ctidary = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]
$ctidary.Add($ctID)
$list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $ctidary
$list.RootFolder.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks Simon for your answer. I already tried this but this is also not working. It requires `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll 16.0` because I am working with SharePoint Online. So for On-Premise solution this is fine, but not for my scenario.

Comment: Whats not working, of course I ment $ctidary=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType]
You must use .Add to add contenttype.

Comment: I already tried .Add also, but it was also giving me the same error. So I tried it with .insert.